# Can we directly use the likelihood function for Bayesian inference?

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, posterior

I'm new to statistics, so this might be obvious.

When doing full Bayesian inference, we first compute the parameter posterior $P(\theta | \text{data})$ using Bayes' rule.

Then, to make a prediction, we compute the predictive posterior by averaging different prediction distributions at different values of $\theta$.

So what happens if we just use the likelihood function $L(\theta)$ in place of $P(\theta | \text{data})$? My hand-wavy motivation is we can average over the likelihoods of different $\theta$s.

(For the sake of argument, let's say we can scale $L(\theta)$ to integrate to 1.)

Comment: You can in principle, but this is not Bayesian inferece/prediction anymore because L(theta) is independent from your prior distribution

Comment: In my understanding, scaling $L(\theta)$ to integrate to 1 is exactly like having an implicit prior with a uniform distribution across all values of $\theta$ (or, if $\theta$ is unbounded - uniform across all values with non-zero likelihood; but let's assume that $ \theta$ is bounded for this matter).

Comment: I do not think that this question already has an answer. In https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37406/likelihood-vs-conditional-distribution-for-bayesian-analysis the question was: what is the difference between $f(X|\theta)$ and $L(\theta|x)$ _in Bayes' theorem_. Here the question is: what happens if we use $L(\theta;x)$ instead of $p(\theta|x)$, i.e. instead of Bayes' theorem?

Comment: IMHO the short answer is: $L(\theta;x)$ can be viewed as a nonnormalized posterior with uniform (constant) prior. You get similar results if a uniform prior does make sense (e.g. when you are looking for the mean of a normal distribution), different results if a uniform prior does not make sense (e.g. when you are looking for the variance of a normal distribution).